# POST Ajax 500 (Internal Server Error) on uploading 12MB file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

in my asp.net mvc project i use ajax post to upload some files in a folder ,it works great except when my file is getting bigger i get this 500 (Internal Server Error).i put a break point on my target controller action but it doesn't hit that.

here are my codes:

```
 $('#txtUploadFile').on('change', function (e) {
    var files = e.target.files;
    var myID = @Model.News.Id; 
    if (files.length > 0) {
        if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
            var data = new FormData();
            for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
                data.append("file" + x, files[x]);
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Admin/UploadFile?id=' + myID,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                    var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
                    if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                        err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("This browser doesn't support HTML5 file uploads!");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to post more than 4MB files to Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630359/not-able-to-post-more-than-4mb-files-to-web-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem.
the error was "Maximum request length exceeded."
the default upload file size is 4MB

added bellow code to my web.config file :

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
</system.web>
```